# How do I get my request data in the django-paypal IPN function?

Tags: python, django, paypal, request, django-1.9

I am building an online store.

My order data are stored in the request. My views have the following general structure:

**payment.py**

```
def payment(request):
    order = request.order    # Getting the order instance
    # do some stuff
    return render_to_response("payment.html")
```

I use `django-paypal`. I am following [this tutorial](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html). The following function is called by PayPal and it signals me that the payment has been successful.

**payment_paypal_ipn_signal_handler.py**

```
# Almost entirely copied from the django-paypal tutorial
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received

def payment_paypal_ipn_signal_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        # WARNING !
        # Check that the receiver email is the same we previously
        # set on the business field request. (The user could tamper
        # with those fields on payment form before send it to PayPal)
        if ipn_obj.receiver_email != "receiver_email@example.com":
            # Not a valid payment
            return

        # ALSO: for the same reason, you need to check the amount
        # received etc. are all what you expect.

        # Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.
        if ipn_obj.custom == "Upgrade all users!":
            Users.objects.update(paid=True)

        # Here I should add the code that handles a successful payment
        request.order.paid = True    # How do I get my 'request' here?
    else:
        #...

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

But, I still need my `order` instance in order to set it as paid, for example. How could I get my data inside this function that is called by PayPal?

Comment: Don't suppose you know how you figured this out? Stuck with the same issue. Docs are terrible :)

Comment: @JDavies ... I did find a solution. Check out my answer, please.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution. You can pass information through the `custom` property in the `PayPalPaymentsForm` parameters.

**payment_paypal.py**

```
def payment_paypal(request):
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": ...,
        "amount": ...,
        ...,
        # Pass any information you want HERE!
        "custom": request.order.order_number,
    }
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"paypal_form": form}
    return render(request, "payment_paypal.html", context)
```

**payment_paypal_ipn_signal_handler.py**

```
def payment_paypal_ipn_signal_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    # Retrieve the order_number previously passed
    order_number = ipn_obj.custom
    # Get the order :D
    order = Orders.objects.get(order_number=order_number)
    ...
```

The order number (or other information) is retrieved in the view that handles the IPN signal.

Comment: i am a bit confused , about IPN signal that gets send and IPN response on view